# I can't Wscript.Run a command created by a subroutine

Tags: vbscript, subroutine, wsh

I have an array of folder/subfolder combinations.  My subroutine grabs the folder combinations, along with constant paths and a provided date-stamp, and builds the command, returning the variable "rcmd" -

```
For each location in myArray
    Call RoboCopy
    MsgBox rcmd
Next


'Sub for the robocopy command   
Sub RoboCopy
    infolder = location
    arr2 = Split(location,"\")
    outfolder = arr2(0)
    rcmd = "robocopy " & IN_PATH & "\" & infolder & " " & OUT_PATH & "\" _
        & outfolder & " /XO /MAXAGE:2 /NP /Log+:C:\OKC_v13_to_v15_copy_" & stamp & ".log"
End Sub
```

As you see, I have "MsgBox" helping right now.  The MsgBox always displays the command I need, correctly.  However, as soon as I try to change it to -

```
For each location in myArray
    Call RoboCopy
    Wsh.Run rcmd, 0, true
Next
```

It doesn't do anything.  Do I need to supply the command I'm trying to run a different way to Wsh.Run?  By the way, Wsh has already been defined as WScript.Shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not use `Robocopy` but I have 2 things in my mind. First, variable named `Wsh` not work for me (not sure why). Second, more important, I think, is that you need to call `CMD.exe`, i.e.:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
For each location in myArray
    Call RoboCopy
    WshShell.Run "cmd /c " & rcmd, 0, True
Next
```

Comment: Oh.  My.  God.  Are you kidding?!  You are absolutely right, Panayot.  For some reason (although it WAS defined, properly), the script engine didn't like me using "Wsh" for my Object.  I did a quick "replace all" and changed everything to "oShell", and it worked fine.  Thank you for the little "Wsh not work for me (not sure why)..."  It was the break I needed!   =)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of thing can go wrong - I'd

1. remove/disable all "On Error Resume Next"
2. prepend "%comspec% /K " to the command and change the intWindowStyle parameter in the .Run call from 0 to 1 (display window)
3. Copy the MsgBox result and execute the command from a command prompt

Comment: I did copy the message box text, and the command runs fine, so I know it's not a syntax issue with the command.  But, I will try the "%comspec% /K", and see how that works.